# Informix DDL execution for constraint disabling

Tags: java, constraints, informix, ddl

I am planning to disable a Foreign Key constraint to avoid a recursive relationship while purging some data. Main steps are written below:

```
Connection conn = getConnection(SI_SINGLE_URL2, SI_UNAME2, SI_PASS2); // will return a valid java,sql.Connection
Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();  
boolean isConstraintDisabled = stmt.execute("ALTER TABLE zee_temp_tab_2 NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL");  
stmt.executeQuery("DELETE FROM zee_temp_tab_2 WHERE id = 'A'");
boolean isConstraintEnabled =  stmt.execute("ALTER TABLE zee_temp_tab_2 CHECK CONSTRAINT ALL");
```

Please advise how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

To disable all constraints for a table (PK, uniques, not null, check)

```
 set constraints for table <table> disabled;
```

or a specific contraint

```
 set constraints <constraint_name> disabled;
```

To enable, just use "enabled" parameter.
Observation: All PK, FKs and UNIQUEs will recreate they internal index... depending of your # of records, maybe take a time.... be careful.

Other options is use the "deferred" option (this way you don't need to disable, but need do everything into a single transaction.)

```
set constraints <ALL|constraint_name> deferred;
begin work;
-- do what you have to do
commit work; -- the constraints will be validated here...
set constraints <ALL|constraint_name> immediate;
```

And there the option "filtered"... but this is little more complex and will need a support of your DBA.

For more information, search for this commands into the [online manual](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/idshelp/v115/index.jsp)

Comment: I do not want to use a stored procedure, I want to do it using JDBC API.

Comment: @Zeeshan , I don't know where you see stored procedure on the commands I describe. They are all Informix statements where you can call with stmt.execute just like your code. Off course you probably will substitute the `begin work` / `commit work` by Informix JDBC calls to control your transaction.